# Adding a conditional value to extra column in pivot table from array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, relationships

I know the Question title is a bit murky, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm retrieving a list of groups that a user belongs to from a third party api. In some cases, the user will be an 'admin' for a group and other times, just a 'member'. 
Specifics aside, I'm calling a method on my api class from my controller that hits the api, retrieves the user's groups, decides if they are an 'admin' or not, then returns an array of arrays with each group's information including a 'role' key that denotes whether or not they are an 'admin'. So my returned array looks something like this:

```
[
  0 => [
    'unique_id' => 1243657,
    'name' => 'Group1',
    'city' => 'Bluesville',
    'state' => 'IN',
    'role' => 'admin'

  ],

  1 => [
    'unique_id' => 4324567,
    'name' => 'Group2',
    'city' => 'New Curtsbourough',
    'state' => 'WI',
    'role' => 'member'
  ],

  2=>  [
    'unique_id' => 87463652,
    'name' => 'Group3',
    'city' => 'Samsonite',
    'state' => 'MN',
    'role' => 'member'
  ]
]
```

Now, I need to take those groups and store them in the database, which I'm doing by checking first that the group doesn't exist in the database, then adding it if needed. Of course, I'm leaving off the role, as it is only relevant to the current user.

Next, I need to connect the current user to these groups that were just retrieved. I have a pivot table set up that currently holds the user_id and group_id.

The question is, how to best handle this. Before I decided that I needed to know whether or not a member was an 'admin' or not, I simply had my 'createGroups' method return an array of primary keys to me, then passed that array to a call to

```
$user->groups()->sync($array_of_ids);
```

However, with the added 'role' information, it's not as cut and dry.

Basically, at this point in the lifecycle, I have access to an array of groups that contains a field 'role'. My thinking says to add a 'role' field to the pivot table, which would then contain 'user_id', 'group_id' and 'role'. This means I'll not only need the $groups array with the retrieved groups, but the ids of those groups as they pertain to my database.

I could make something work, but I'm afraid it would be extremely messy and inefficient.

Thoughts anyone??

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as happens many times on Stackoverflow, I've come to a solution for my own question. I'm posting so that in the off-chance someone stumbles upon my question needing to do something similar, they can at least see how one person handled it.

According to the Laravel docs, if you want to sync relationships with an added column, you need to call sync in the following way:

```
$user->groups()->sync([
    1 => ['role' => 'admin'], 
    2 => ['role' => 'member'], 
    3 => ['role' => 'member']
]);
```

So before I could sync, I needed an array that resembled the array that is being passed to 'sync'.

Since I had an array of 'groups' that included a field called 'role' for each group, I created a 'createGroups' method that basically looped over the $groups array and called the 'insertGetId' method that Laravel provides. This method persists the object to the database and returns the primary key of the created record. For my 'createGroups' method, I did the following:

```
public function createGroups($groups)
{
    $added = array();
    foreach($groups as $group){
        $id = $this->createGroup($group);
        $added[$id] = ['role' => $group['role']];
    }

    return $added;
}
```

So as I'm inserting 'groups' into the database, I'm building up the array that is needed by the 'sync' method. Since the 'createGroup' method uses Laravel's 'insertGetId' method, it returns the primary key for that group. Then I use that id as the key to the array. After all groups are inserted, my 'added' array that is returned to my controller, looks like this:

```
[
    1 => ['role' => 'admin'], 
    2 => ['role' => 'member'], 
    3 => ['role' => 'member']
]
```

which is exactly what the 'sync' method needs to do it's thing.

Happy coding!